# "sanic tried to use loop.add_signal_handler but it is not implemented on this platform" windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, sanic

I am trying to run the basic sanic app on windows 10.

```
from sanic import Sanic
from sanic.response import json
app = Sanic('just-try')

@app.route("/")
async def test(request):
  return json({"hello": "world"})

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8000,workers=1)
```

But it is just stuck there showing this warning

`sanic tried to use loop.add_signal_handler but it is not implemented on this platform`

[image]

sanic - 19.12.2

python - 3.7.6 (anaconda env)

OS - windows 10

installed sanic by running-

```
set SANIC_NO_UVLOOP=true
set SANIC_NO_UJSON=true
pip install sanic
```

note: I had to manually download and copy aiofiles, hpack, hyperframe, h11, rfc3986, and hstspreload to the site-packages folder. otherwise getting `import error`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to install sanic from git.

```
set SANIC_NO_UVLOOP=true
set SANIC_NO_UJSON=true
pip install git+https://github.com/huge-success/sanic.git
```

They will release version 20.3 with windows related bugs fixed.